Is it normal to see light between the plywood on a roof deck?
I am replacing my roof and needed plywood changed out due to water damage. They have completed the decking and are waiting for inspection prior to putting the other layers. Is it normal to see light between the plywood seams in the attic at this stage?

It is the size of the opening.  Drop a coin down okay.  Drop a hammer down not as good.

There is actually a requirement that the plywood sheets are not tight against each other.
The normal spacing is about 1/8 inch or the thickness of a nickel.
Some installers use Plywood clips to keep the spacing and help even edges together.

This is to allow for expansion of the plywood, preventing buckling.

This despite the fact that plywood is "dimensionally stable". Under the intense heat often generated in a roof, even plywood expands.
